# Exponential derivative of delta distribution?

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

This question is essentially [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365329/distribution-integral-result), but uses a different phrasing that hopefully might attract the attention of different people who might be able to help.

The question is, what is the result of the following integral for integer $n$ and real $x$?

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\, e^{ny}e^{iyx}$$

Does it diverge and give infinity, or is it actually just equal to the following?

$$=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{n^m}{m!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\, y^m e^{iyx}=2\pi\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{m!}\left(-in\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^m\delta(x)=2\pi \left(e^{-in\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\delta(x)\right)$$

More importantly, is there some book or scientific article on distributions that discusses this? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a distribution $D(x,n)$ such that $\int f(x)D(x-x_{0},n)dx = f(x_{0}-n)$ by the Taylor series for $f(x)$ about $x_{0}$?

Comment: @AlexNelson nope, there is no $i$ in the exponential $e^{ny}$, which means it is not just a shift of $x$. Or in other words $x$ and $y$ are both real, while the shift would be in the imaginary direction, which is not allowed.

Comment: right, sorry, I missed that (haven't had coffee yet today!); but it would be (in that case) a Laurent series expansion, $\int f(x) D(x - x_{0}, n)dx = 2\pi f(x_{0} + in)$

Comment: @AlexNelson Could you elaborate a bit on the resulting Laurent series? Is there some literature on it in the above context? The result $f(x_0+in)$ still looks like a complex shift was performed, but the integral representation of delta function is only valid for real arguments $x$. Which is why the above question comes up in the first place.

Comment: I think something might be wrong with your initial integral, since $\delta(x) = \int \exp(iyx)dy$ then its derivative would be $\delta'(x) = \int iy\exp(iyx)dy$...so $\exp(nd/dx)\delta(x) = \int\exp(iyn)\exp(iyx)dy$, modulo some factor of $2\pi$. Afterall $\int\exp(ny)\exp(ixy)dy=\int\exp(iy[x-in])dy$.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $e^{nx}$ is not defined in the theory of distributions unless $n=0$. The function grows too fast.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks for pointing that out! Do you know of some reference that discusses this so I can read about it in more detail?

Comment: Wikipedia has [some information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) about it.